# How can I parse these strings into UTC dates?

Tags: javascript, timezone, date-parsing

I'm scraping a site, and the dates come in two forms:

```
11-22-2011 07:41 AM
Today @ 07:41 AM
```

Both of these are GMT-8. I'd like to get a unix timestamp out of these, so that I can construct a meaningful date object

Any idea what timezone this might be? Around a month ago, the site was gibing GMT-9 times. Can javascript handle Daylight Saving Time automatically?

I'm having great difficultly parsing them. Part of the problem is the time zone.

At the moment, I'm using Date.js' `parseExact`:

```
date = Date.parseExact(date + ' PDT', 'MM-dd-yyyy H:mm tt zzz');
```

Hovever, this seems to get parse 12AM as `12:00`, not `0:00`. Additionally, I'm at a total loss as to how to handle the ones starting with `today @`.

Comment: "12 AM" isn't well-defined; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight

Comment: @Wooble: I realize. However, when I recieve 12 AM, I know it should be interpreted as `0:00` on the morning of the same day

Comment: I don't think this question deserves a down vote. It's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @Wooble - That wikipedia article is, IMHO, nitpicky, and perhaps even flat out incorrect.  The crux of the argument is that AM means the 12 hour period following midnight and that midnight is not *after* midnight.  In truth, AM means "before midday" from the latin *ante meridiem*.  Since midnight starts the new day, AM is indeed correct and, I'd say, unambiguous.  The article conceeds that computers, digital clocks, and even the US Government Manual of style all express midnight as 12:00 AM.  It provides not one reference of 12:00 AM having a different meaning in any other culture or context.

Comment: "The 29th edition of the U.S. Government Printing Office Style Manual (2000) section 12.9 recommended the opposite the use of "12 p.m." for midnight" from the same article. It's not even unambiguous in US government documents; it depends when they were published.

Answer (score 1):

When I try both of your examples using the interactive parser at http://www.datejs.com/ I get the expected results.

The timezone in question is likely "US West Coast", aka "Pacific Time".

Unfortunately that means different things at different times of the year.  In the spring and summer that timezone is called "PDT" (GMT-0700) and the rest of the time it's called "PST" (GMT-0800).

To further complicate matters the dates on which that changes aren't the same as the dates on which other zones (e.g. in Europe) change.

I don't think there's a way of specifying a timezone value to Date.js that can take that into account automatically.

Comment: The `Today @` one does not work near boundaries. The today is ignored, so it is incorrectly parsed as "Today where you are at 7:41 PST", instead of "7:41 on the day it is in the PST time zone". As a result, it can end up off by a day.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own, timezone-aware date parsing logic which takes into account the timezone of the remote server.

pseudo-code:

```
if date starts with "Today @"
  replace "Today @" with currentDateInRemoteTimezone in date
endif

parse_timezone-aware(date)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to get `currentDateInRemoteTimezone`

Comment: You would have to find out which timezone the server is working in and define how that timezone differs to UTC at time of parsing. I didn't say it would be easy. Sorry :)

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/mde/timezone-js ? I didn't have the time to check for myself but the description looks like it could come in handy.

Comment: That does indeed look useful. Where can I find these "Olson time zone files"?

Comment: I've got the problem that this is running in an environment where an XHR is plain silly (a chrome extension). There's mention of some "precompiled json", but no description of the format, and I don't have access to the tools to generate it. Plus, I couldn't find the instructions on how to tell it to use the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add `HHHH:mm zzz` to get 12:00?

Answer (score 0):

Use a lowercase `h` for the hour to get 1-12.  The uppercase `H` gives 0-23.  From your examples I would use a format of

```
MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt
```

[Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers)

You should handle "Today @ " separately.  When you find that string, expect the next token to be a time in the form `hh:mm tt`.  Parse the second part as a time and combine it with today's (local) date.  That is not hard to do programmatically with Date.js functions, but you won't find a single format string that captures the "Today @" part (as you know).

Comment: Whoops. I copied the wrong line of code. I meant to have lowercase h

Comment: The issue is I don't want the "local" today - I want the "remote" today.